# Offer templating functionality in a WPF application - how to?

Tags: c#, wpf, templates

I have a dream:

Im working on a note-taking application, where everyone can store notes and tag them. Now, it would be nice if the users could use the application for several purposes: Store book-information, recipes, checklists etc...

[Book-information template http://dl.danielgilbert.de/templatetable.png](http://dl.danielgilbert.de/templatetable.png)

Here we have a book-information template. I could imagine a template selector underneath the title box, where you could select a template to enter information in an organized way. But I'm stuck.

- How would you actually "load" or "create" such a template?
- How would you store the data entered?
- How would you enable basic formatting options in the textfields?
- And finally: I would need a non-editable template for the overview, filled with the data that has been entered in the edit-mode.

I know, it's not an easy question, but maybe there are some pretty good ideas out there. :)

Comment: Do you know the "universe" of templates in advance or should the user be allowed to create new templates?

Comment: Do you need one template for each entity(book, note, ...) or many? And can users create new entities?

Comment: I think `ContentControl.ContentTemplate`, `ContentControl.Content`, `DataTemplate.DataType` and MVVM will provide you exactly what you seek. http://www.japf.fr/2009/03/thinking-with-mvvm-data-templates-contentcontrol/

Comment: @MartinLiversage No, the User should be able to create new templates. And thanks for embedding the image. :)

Comment: @Ivan.Benko No, I need one Template for each entity. And I'm still searching a smart solution to save everything.

Comment: @AngelWPF Thanks for the link, I'll have a look at it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

obviously it's pretty dead simple to achieve what I want: If you enter anything into a control, it will be serialized if you use the XamlWriter. I could store the serialized Xaml and read it back when the note gets loaded. So, finally, the user will end up with a file where he enters some Markup like:

```
<CheckBox >test</CheckBox>
<Label>Huhu</Label>
<TextBox Foreground="Gray">This is a test...</TextBox>
<Label>Huhu</Label>
<TextBox Foreground="Gray">This is a test...</TextBox>
```

And in the Edit-Screen, the whole markup will be serialized with it's values.

However, this has the drawback that you cannot change the template once assigned, or you cannot change the layout if the basic template changes. Maybe I'll get an idea how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection and custom attributes.

I implement similar functionality in my wp7 application (but it doesn't matter, xaml is xaml everywhere).

Idea is to create super view(control) that can display any entity. Create for each entity class, representing this entity, and add custom attributes to properties of this class (which tell super view how to display entity)
Super view should analize these attributes and construct view.

This is [part of my project](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=A9F5C8F1AFB7D88B&id=A9F5C8F1AFB7D88B!229):

I hope this information helps you.

Comment: Ok, so you would create a view which automatically consumes an entity. This is a pretty neat idea! :) However, it would make it difficult for the average user to create his "own" template. Maybe I should load the XAML-Template on runtime via XAMLReader, and - when the user saves it - serialize the whole template including it's values.

Comment: @DanielGilbert, In my project I use this for editing simple objects without creating many xaml pages for it (f.e. user settings). This is only idea for you, not solution..

Comment: Nevermind, as I already said, it's pretty nice and smart. Really. ;) But I guess, this would be way too complicated for an average enduser. I'll do a little more brainstorming...